# command line when inserted, program wont run

Tags: c, command-line

I'm just lost. My code is running well if I delete the admin reset part, meanwhile when I run the program with the admin reset part and input "reset" as a parameter. the admin reset part resets what it needs to reset. In short, separately they are working but together it wont run as in when i click the build and run button(in codeblocks) it will show the console for a while and then windows will pop a "program.exe has stopped working" dialog box. what's wrong? Here I just paste the first part.

```
///admin reset
if(strcmp(argv[1], "reset")==0){
    printf("Hello admin. You now have the power to reset the program.\n Press 'y' to proceed or press any key yo cancel: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    if (choice == 'y'){
        remove("db.txt");
        remove("phonebook.txt");
        printf("Program will now exit. Thank You. Good day.\n");
    }
}
///retrieve data
    db = fopen("db.txt", "r");

    if (db==NULL){
    printf("\a");
    db = NULL;
    } else {
    ReadLine(db, savedu, sizeof(char[16]));
    ReadLine(db, savedp, sizeof(char[16]));
    fscanf(db, "%d" , &cc);
    pb = (Myphonebooktype*)malloc(cc*sizeof(Myphonebooktype));
    addcounter = cc;


    for(i = 0; i<cc ; i++) {
        fscanf(db, "%d" , &pb[i].num);
        ReadLine(db, pb[i].name, sizeof pb[i].name);
        ReadLine(db, pb[i].address, sizeof pb[i].address);
        ReadLine(db, pb[i].cellphone, sizeof pb[i].cellphone);
        ReadLine(db, pb[i].email, sizeof pb[i].email);
        }
    }

///register and login
if(db==NULL){
    while(1){
        printf("Username and password should not exceed 15 charcaters\nRegister/Login (press enter to exit)\nUsername: ");
        gets(username);

        if (strcmp(username, "") == 0) {
            option = 'X';
            break;
        }

        if(strlen(username)>=16){
            printf("\a");
            printf("username should not exceed 15 characters.\n");
            continue;
        }

        printf("Password: ");
        gets(password);

        if (strcmp(password, "") == 0) {
            option = 'X';
            break;
        }
        if(strlen(password)>=16){
            printf("\a");
            printf("password should not exceed 15 characters\n");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
} else {...
```

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: it just wont run. exit immediately after i click run

Comment: "... but together it wont compile" - does it compile or not then? If it doesn't compile, what's the error message? If it "doesn't run", you'll need to describe that in more detail, and use a debugger to figure out where it's failing exactly.

Comment: Btw Avoid using **gets**, it's very dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be if(argc==2 && strcmp(argv[1], "reset")==0)

Comment: Actually it might be the answer. I don't see that the OP checks the argument count, so if he starts the program with no paramter at all `argv[1]` could cause a crash. Nevertheless some explanation would have been really good.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that with a little "debugging" you will be able to pinpoint where the faulty code lays.

look at [codeblocks debugger how to](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code%3a%3aBlocks)

Alternatively, you can use Visual Studio which has powerful debugging capabilities.